# How to hierarchically cluster a data matrix in R?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I am trying to cluster a data matrix produced from scientific data. I know how I want the clustering done, but am not sure how to accomplish this feat in R.

Here is what the data looks like:

```
            A1     A2     A3     B1     B2     B3     C1     C2     C3
sample1      1      9     10      2      1     29      2      5     44
sample2      8      1     82      2      8      2      8      2     28
sample3      9      9     19      2      8      1      7      2     27
```

Please consider A1,A2,A3 to be three replicates of a single treatment, and likewise with B and C. Sample1 are different tested variables. So, I want to hierarchically cluster this matrix in order to see the over all differences between the columns, specifically I will be making a dendrogram (tree) to observe the relatedness of the columns.

Does anyone know how to appropriately cluster something like this? I tried doing this with this:

```
raw.data <- read.delim("test.txt",header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dist.mat<-vegdist(raw.data,method="jaccard")
clust.res<-hclust(dist.mat)
plot(clust.res)
```

...However, this resulted in a tree with branches for each sample variable, instead of each column. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Try `vegdist(t(raw.data), method="jaccard")` to transpose your matrix before calculate the distance. Isn't *Jaccard* only for binary data?

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Off the heels of that problem, does anyone know how to do the same thing, but using Jensen-Shannon method instead of Jaccard? The Jaccard method gave unexpected results, probably due to improper data for Jaccard!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just transpose your data set:

```
raw.data <- t(raw.data)
require(vegan)
dist.mat<-vegdist(raw.data,method="jaccard")
clust.res<-hclust(dist.mat)
plot(clust.res)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Would you happen to know how to do the same using Jensen-Shannon instead of Jaccard?

Comment: You may want to check out `designdist` from the vegan package. It allows one to define alternate distance / dissimilarity matrices: http://cc.oulu.fi/~jarioksa/softhelp/vegan/html/designdist.html