# Find Jaccard distance of tweets and cluster in Kmeans

Tags: json, r, algorithm, twitter, k-means

This is a follow up question to a problem I've been working on for a while.  I have two questions. One regards an algorithm that works on two tweets, that I revised to measure 10 tweets. I'm wondering what my revision is measuring.  I get result, but I want it to measure several tweet's jaccard distances, not just return one value.  Since it's returning one value, I think it's just adding everything up. The other question is about my attempt to create a For Loop and assign clusters.

I'm trying to find the Jaccard distance between a dataset of tweets, then cluster those tweets with the Kmeans algorithm.

This is where I'm retrieving the data from:
http://www3.nd.edu/~dwang5/courses/spring15/assignments/A2/Tweets.json

What I have so far is this

```
    install.packages("rjson")
library("rjson")


#download JSON File and put into a dataframe
download.file("http://www3.nd.edu/~dwang5/courses/spring15/assignments/A2/Tweets.json", tf<-tempfile());library(jsonlite);json_alldata <- fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]", paste(readLines(file(tf)),collapse=",")))

# get rid of geo column
tweet.features = json_alldata
tweet.features$geo <- NULL

# *Works.   Compares two tweets and measures Jaccard Distance

tweetText <- list(tweet1 = tweet.features$text[1]:tweet.features$text[2])

jaccard_i <- function(tw1, tw2){
  tw1 <- unlist(strsplit(tw1, " |\\."))
  tw2 <- unlist(strsplit(tw2, " |\\."))
  i <- length(intersect(tw1, tw2))
  u <- length(union(tw1, tw2))

  list(i=i, u=u, j=i/u)
}

jaccard_i(tweetText[[1]], tweetText[[2]])
```

All of that measures the jaccard distance of two specified tweets.  Which is great.

But now I'm trying to modify to compare the distances between several tweets. This time 10 random tweets which I retrieved from the Sample command in R.

```
# Generates two sets of 5 random tweets
tweetText <- list(sample(tweet.features$text, replace = FALSE, size = 5), sample(tweet.features$text, replace = FALSE, size = 5))

jaccard_i <- function(tw1, tw2){
  tw1 <- unlist(strsplit(tw1, " |\\."))
  tw2 <- unlist(strsplit(tw2, " |\\."))
  i <- length(intersect(tw1, tw2))
  u <- length(union(tw1, tw2))

  list(i=i, u=u, j=i/u)
}

jaccard_i(tweetText[[1]], tweetText[[2]])
```

This gives me results, but it can't be correct.

I'm trying to build an algorithm that can measure all the tweets, compare their jaccard distance, then cluster based on the Jaccard distance with Kmeans.

So for another attempt, I thought to make a For Loop.

I decided to make 10 cluster centers with the 10 random tweets

```
c <- sample(tweet.features$text, replace = FALSE, size = 10)
```

Now I did a For Loop hoping to measure the tweets which I figured I could assign to an array and cluster

```
#Algorithm attempt
for(i in tweet.features$text){
  for (j in c){
    i <- length(intersect(i, j))
    u <- length(union(i, j))
    j = i/u
  }
  #assign(my.array)
}
```

I don't believe that's doing anything useful, but it's an attempt to create a loop to measure the Jaccard distance.

I'm sorry that this is a loaded question.   Any help would be appreciated as I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Have a look at the `stringdist` or `vegan` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first function, you are doing `unlist` of your lists of words in your tweets, thus in `tw1` and `tw2` have the global lists of words and you cannot use them for your tweet-by-tweet Jaccard. You could accomplish it with a removing the `unlist`, then `tw1` and `tw2` are lists of lists of terms, and you can compare them using `mapply`. Something as follows.

```
jaccard_i <- function(tw1, tw2){
  tw1 <- strsplit(tw1, " |\\.")
  tw2 <- strsplit(tw2, " |\\.")
  i <- mapply(function(tw1, tw2) {
    length(intersect(tw1, tw2))
  }, tw1=tw1, tw2=tw2)
  u <- mapply(function(tw1, tw2) {
    length(union(tw1, tw2))
  }, tw1=tw1, tw2=tw2)
  list(i=i, u=u, j=i/u)
}
```

Silly example:

```
> tw1 = c("we yes you no", "we are the people")
> tw2= c("we are the people", "we yes you no")
> tweetText = list(tw1, tw2)
> jaccard_i(tweetText[[1]], tweetText[[2]])
$i
[1] 1 1

$u
[1] 7 7

$j
[1] 0.1428571 0.1428571
```

As for the second part of your question, the double loop, an easy way to start addressing it would be like this,

```
tw = c("we yes you no", "we are the people")
lapply(tw, function(tweet1) {
  lapply(tw, function(tweet2) {
    jaccard_i(tweet1, tweet2)
  })
})
```

With results that look like this,

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]]$i
[1] 4

[[1]][[1]]$u
[1] 4

[[1]][[1]]$j
[1] 1


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]]$i
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]$u
[1] 7

[[1]][[2]]$j
[1] 0.1428571



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]]$i
[1] 1

[[2]][[1]]$u
[1] 7

[[2]][[1]]$j
[1] 0.1428571


[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]]$i
[1] 4

[[2]][[2]]$u
[1] 4

[[2]][[2]]$j
[1] 1
```

where you should skip the values in the diagonals of course -just a starting point as I said.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.  Instead of specifying the tweets in tw1 and tw2, I replaced with this  (same as I used before) and then used the first function you provided. tweetText <- list(sample(tweet.features$text, replace = FALSE, size = 5), sample(tweet.features$text, replace = FALSE, size = 5))  It appears to be comparing/measuring the 1st tweet in the first sample, vs. the first tweet in the second and so on.  Do you think that's ok to use, or should I do something else?

Comment: Well, I was just following your question and trying to answer. I actually think your second idea with the 2 loops is better, you need to compare every tweet versus every tweet, you'll need it for clustering. But I also guess that you are trying to learn how to do it, since there are libraries that could do most of the stuff for you.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try to work with the second one. And yes, I am trying to learn this stuff.  It's a bit overwhelming, to be honest.  What libraries do you recommend that could help me with this?  I researched stuff on Vegan prior to asking this question, but I wasn't sure how to modify to do what I wanted.

Comment: You're more than welcome. Take a look to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18134177/3519000), it uses `vegan` for calculating the distance matrix and `hclust` (which is just in the packet stats, you don't have to install anything) for clustering. (Actually, kmeans seems to behave not so well with jaccard -I havent used it myself, and people tend to use hierarchical clustering for texts -I have tried it and it works well). Cheers.