# R Apply a function to matrix where each vector (row) is an argument

Tags: r, matrix, sapply

I am trying to write a function to apply a function to each row in a matrix, but the problem is I need each vector(row) in the matrix to be used as an argument for the function. I'm using sapply so I can store it as a result matrix and sort it.

What I have so far is

```
r=apply(m,1,cosineSim(x['word',]))
```

where cosineSim is defined as

```
cosineSim <- function(v1,v2){
 a <- sum(v1*v2)
 b <- sqrt(sum(v1*v1))* sqrt(sum(v2*v2))
 return(a/b)
}
```

But the problem I'm having is I can't figure out how to use each vector that's being applied as an argument for the cosine function which takes two vectors. I have one vector, but the second is supposed to be the current row that the apply function is on.  I'm new to R so please forgive me if my solution is trivial. Thanks for any help.

Some sample data I'm working with includes:

```
    the 0.41800  0.249680 -0.41242  0.121700 0.345270 -0.044457 -0.49688 -0.178620 -0.00066023 -0.656600 0.278430 -0.14767 -0.55677  0.14658 -0.0095095
    .   0.15164  0.301770 -0.16763  0.176840 0.317190  0.339730 -0.43478 -0.310860 -0.44999000 -0.294860 0.166080  0.11963 -0.41328 -0.42353  0.5986800
    of  0.70853  0.570880 -0.47160  0.180480 0.544490  0.726030  0.18157 -0.523930  0.10381000 -0.175660 0.078852 -0.36216 -0.11829 -0.83336  0.1191700
    to  0.68047 -0.039263  0.30186 -0.177920 0.429620  0.032246 -0.41376  0.132280 -0.29847000 -0.085253 0.171180  0.22419 -0.10046 -0.43653  0.3341800
    and 0.26818  0.143460 -0.27877  0.016257 0.113840  0.699230 -0.51332 -0.473680 -0.33075000 -0.138340 0.270200  0.30938 -0.45012 -0.41270 -0.0993200
    in  0.33042  0.249950 -0.60874  0.109230 0.036372  0.151000 -0.55083 -0.074239 -0.09230700 -0.328210 0.095980 -0.82269 -0.36717 -0.67009  0.4290900
```

This is a small example of the matrix I'm working with and I'm trying to use each of those rows as a vector for my cosineSim function.

Comment: Try `apply(x, 1, function(x).......)`

Comment: Please provide some data so that we can replicate your problem. See these tips on asking questions on SO: [minimum example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The problem I'm having is that my function takes 2 arguments and I need each row to be an argument. For example, the first time it runs there's an argument that stays constant, but the second argument, v2 is changed to the value of each vector of the array and I don't know how to specify that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you trying to build a dissimilarity matrix? That is, to compare each row of your matrix versus each other row? If that's the case, maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36497261/3519000) would help -it is for jaccard instead of cosine, but the same double loop should work. If I misunderstood, please provide more details. Thanks.